# Como abrir distintas webs desde el mismo activity

Tags: android-studio

Tengo una `Activity` que tiene 5 botones, la idea es que cada boton abra una webview distinta, solo logre que abra un boton, pero para el resto no logro hacerlo:
Activity con las cards y los botones

```
public class CardStats extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_stats);
        Button info = findViewById(R.id.containedButton1);//boton 1
        info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), StatsActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`StatsActivity:`

```
public class StatsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stats);

        WebView myWebview ;
        myWebview  = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebview.loadUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/");
    }
}
```

Ahora falta hacer que los otros botones, de la primer `activty` abra otras webs

Comment: Estás diciendo que el ```WebView``` y el ```Button``` no están el la misma **Activity** ?? Según tu código, indicas que ambos están en ```activity_stats.xml``` . Es así?

Comment: Claro, ahi los puse en el mismo `activity_stats` pero en realidad el button no esta en el mismo activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasa un valor **Extra**, entre pantallas. Un ejemplo con dos botones. Fíjate...

`CardStats`

```
  public class CardStats extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_stats);

    Button info = findViewById(R.id.containedButton1);//boton 1
    Button alert= findViewById(R.id.containedButton2);//boton 2   uno de tus otros botones

    info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), StatsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("clave", "info"); // este valor pasará a la segunda activity indicando qué botón pulsaste
            startActivityIntent(intent);  
        }
    });


   alert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), StatsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("clave", "alert"); // este valor pasará a la segunda activity indicando qué botón pulsaste
            startActivityIntent(intent);  
        }
    });

  }
}
```

En la segunda activity recuperas el valor **Extra** para decidir qué web mostrar

`StatsActivity`

```
public class StatsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stats);
    
    WebView myWebview = findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    String clave = getIntent().getStringExtra("clave");
    switch (clave) {
                case "info":  // si se pulsó el botón info se abre esta web
                    myWebview.loadUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/");
                    break;
                case "alert":  // si se pulsó el botón alert se abre esta web
                    myWebview.loadUrl("https://es.wikipedia.org/");
                    break;
                default:
                    //Página que se abrirá por defecto;
            } myWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }

 }
```

Comment: Gracias, lo hice similar, pero funciono igual.